# Can we create persistent menu button in the typing bar of microsoft azure bot in Node.js in webapp?

Tags: azure, botframework

SDK Platform: Node.js
Active Channels: Web Chat
Deployment Environment: Azure Bot Service
Can we create persistent menu button in the typing bar of bot in Node.js?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXGPP.png)  Please refer image: I want to add a menu button in typing bar of bot.

Comment: The link you are providing is specific about Facebook Start Button and you are talking about webchat deployment, please edit your question with a clear sentence and what you made so far

Answer (score 0):

With Bot Framework you are able to use 'suggested actions' as part of your dialog. As the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-send-suggested-actions) show, it produces a menu just above the typing bar. The menu options disappear after the user has made a choice and re-appear again if the user triggers the associated dialog.

Visit this [site](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/channel-inspector/channels/WebChat?f=SuggestedActions&e=example1) for a visual sense of the look.

Here is a code sample you can reference. Hope this helps.

Steve.

```
bot.dialog('/', [
    function (session) {

        var msg = new builder.Message(session)
            .text("Hi! What is your favorite color?")
            .suggestedActions(
                builder.SuggestedActions.create(
                    session,[
                        builder.CardAction.imBack(session, "green", "green"),
                        builder.CardAction.imBack(session, "blue", "blue"),
                        builder.CardAction.imBack(session, "red", "red")
                    ]
                )
            );
        builder.Prompts.choice(session, msg, ["green", "blue", "red"]);
    },
    function(session, results) {
        session.send('I like ' +  results.response.entity + ' too!');
    }
]);
```